# 64 bits native types atomicy and memory bus?

Tags: c, cpu, cpu-architecture, atomic

I have read at some point that native types are atomic as long as they are not wider than the memory bus and aligned. I may be very wrong on this, but isn't a memory bus usually 64-bits even for a 32bits CPU (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-side_bus)? In which case the above statement would mean that a read or write or an aligned 64bits native type would be atomic right? I looked into intel's documentation and it says x86 is guaranteed to be atomic for 32 bits and below only - but I wanted to make sure I understand the memory bus width part correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are asking yourself the wrong question. If the access to a particular integer type is atomic, your compiler will know this. Modern Compilers either implement the new C11 `_Atomic` or similar things as extensions to previous versions of the standard. Use them, whenever you have need for atomic operations.

Answer (score 2):

The width of the memory bus has nothing whatsoever to do with the atomicity of memory accesses. You could have a one-bit memory bus and still have atomic 64-bit memory accesses by holding the bus through 64 reads or writes. You could have a 64-bit bus but not atomic 64-bit memory accesses if the path between the CPU and the cache was 32-bits and the cache could not be locked.

Comment: Yes.  Definitely more than a compiler or CPU issue, but an architecture/system issue as well.

Comment: I am not extremely familiar with CPU architecture, I just wanted to make sure a 64 bit native was not atomic on a 32 bit CPU with a 64 bit wide bus.So, what guarantees that a 32 bit native type is atomic on x86 and why wouldn't it guarantee that a 64 byte native type is not (as opposed to x64) when the bus may be 64bit? Also, "what" would hold the bus to make a 64-bit read atomic on a 32bit CPU?

Comment: A 64-bit native may or may not be atomic on a 32-bit CPU with a 64-bit bus. You'd have to check the documentation for the specific platform or CPU. 32-bit x86 CPUs often have atomic 64-bit operations like [CMPXCHG8B](http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/cmpxchg8b.htm). As for what would hold the bus, it's implementation dependent. In the old days (original Pentium), there was an actual "LOCK" line that the CPU would assert. On more modern platforms, the cache line(s) are locked in place in the L1 cache making the operations atomic because other CPUs can't get the cache line(s) until they're released.